# Get woocommerce product tag slugs as an array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

How to get woocommerce tag slug names to an array correctly? I'm using the following code but it doesn't output anything.

```
    <?php 

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );

        $sluglist = array();
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $sluglist[] = $term->slug;
            }
        }

    echo count($sluglist);

    ?>
```

Comment: First `print_r($terms)` and check what are you getting in that.then try the `foreach ( $terms as $term )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) WordPress function instead this way to get the term slugs in an array with one line of code

```
$term_slugs = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_tag', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );

// The term slugs count
echo count($term_slugs);

// Testing: The raw output (preformatted)
echo '<pre>'; print_r($term_slugs); echo '</pre>';
```